# What were the objects Rey was salvaging in the Star Destroyer hangar?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, object-identification

In *The Force Awakens*, Rey is shown salvaging components from cylindrical structures in a crashed Star Destroyer's hangar. Is there any information (cue the *TFA Visual Dictionary*, *Incredible Cross-Sections*, etc.) on the function of those components and what they're called?

Comment: they sort looked like [explosive charges](https://www.google.com/search?q=star+wars+charges&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=657&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji-MjUlZHKAhUO-GMKHVmhC_UQ_AUICCgD#tbm=isch&q=star+wars+explosive+charges&imgrc=iG3a-T_XekgWCM%3A) to me.

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty convincing, given the image from the authorised companion book. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Comment: The question was not about the objects she was salvaging; it was about the structures she was salvaging from. The question has been modified for more clarity. Sorry about the confusion. :\

Comment: @user339676 - Given that there's an answer to the (amended) question, the appropriate action would be to ask a **completely new question**, rather than invalidating the existing answer by changing the question. For that reason, I'm rolling back to the earlier edit.

Comment: And yes, I do appreciate that your original question was edited in the first place.

Comment: Very well. The earlier edit will also need to be edited for grammatical compliance with the given answers (as in, the "from" will need to be deleted from the title). Also, I didn't see your comment and edited the question a second time. Apologies.

Comment: Done. I have modified the question to be in compliance with the answers rather than its original intent. The "from" was deleted from the title and the final word "objects" has been changed to "components" to remove confusion. Valorum's answer has been accepted.

Comment: @user339676 - Awesome. Don't forget to ask the new question. I may have an answer for that as well.

Comment: @Valorum Posted here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134071/what-were-the-cylindrical-structures-rey-was-salvaging-from-in-the-star-destroye

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE:** According to the [Force Awakens: Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary) they were "*Capacitor Bearings*". Quite why a capacitor needs a bearing isn't explained.

[image]

---

The [script](http://www.cosmicbooknews.com/content/star-wars-force-awakens-script-leaks-online) describes them as "*various mechanisms*"

> A metal sheet is pulled open to reveal the wrapped up faceof A SCAVENGER, perhaps alien, in GOGGLES, FACE MASK and GLOVES.
>   Backpack with a STAFF strapped to it. Uses TOOLS to remove various
>   MECHANISMS from inside the wall. We are in an upside-down, canted
>   CORRIDOR. The Scavenger finds a valuable piece, drops it in a SATCHEL.

The [Junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(junior_novelization)) is similarly enlightening, referring to them as "*various components*"

> She hung on to the wall of a demolished destroyer and used her tools
>   to wiggle free **various components** that rust hadn’t devoured. The ship
>   was a treasure trove of **metal sheeting and military-grade tech** that,
>   if given a proper cleaning, could fetch Rey a meal or two at Niima
>   Outpost.

The [Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel)) is just about as forthcoming, noting that they're "*small devices*"

> Wielding an assortment of tools, **the scavenger was excising an
>   assortment of small devices from one metal wall.** One after another,
>   bits of booty found their way into the satchel that hung below the
>   slender figure.
>
> When the satchel was full, the scavenger secured it shut and commenced
>   a perilous descent, avoiding sharp projections and threatening gaps in
>   the wall. Arriving at the bottom of the metallic canyon, the figure
>   hefted a piece of larger salvage recovered earlier and then, laboring
>   under the double load, headed toward a distant slit of sunlight.

Comment: LOL. Thanks for the answer, although none of the official quotes really seem to clarify anything. :) The objects resemble the things that TIE Fighters hang off of in the games and Original Trilogy, though I can't be completely sure.

Comment: @Richard - My guess would be 'Capacitor Bearings' means that they use EM fields/capacitance instead of smooth material (a.k.a. ball bears) to prevent friction.